# Vuejs - $slots have 'el' is null

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-slot

WHen I access Vuejs $slots instance I get `el = null` but `type = "div"`

template:

```
  <slot name="head">
    <h1>
      {{ text }}
    </h1>
  </slot>
```

script

```
  ...
  const slotCont = this.$slots.head();
  console.log(slotCont[0]);
```

the .el is null event though we've added sd

parent

```
<custom-component :key="human.id">
    <template #head>
      <div style="display: flex;">
        this is Head
      </div>
    </template>

    <template #default>
     <h1>Head</h1>
    </template>
</custom-tooltip>
```

console.log

```
anchor: null
appContext: null
children: (2) [{…}, {…}]
component: null
dirs: null
dynamicChildren: null
dynamicProps: null
el: null <-- element is null
...
type: "div" <-- div is passed
```

Error:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'el')

Comment: Did you try referencing `head` as a property instead of calling it as a function ?

Comment: yeah I've tried this.$slots.head; same error

Comment: The error means that you are trying to read the `el` property from a variable which is NULL (in your case - `slotCont`)

Comment: it's equivalent to -> this.$slots.head[0].el coz I'm trying to get the element inside the slot

Comment: Where are you calling `this.$slots.head`? From the parent component or the component which declares the slot?

Answer (score 0):

`vm.$slots` and `vm.$scopedSlots` refers to **slot inputs** passed to the component.

So **if you didn't provided any `<template #head>` in your component, it won't appear inside these properties**.

AFAIK, you can't access the default slot from the `vm` object, Vue renders it as if it was not even in a slot in the first place. You'll need to query that element in a different way.

Comment: I have updated my question, I have added <template #head></template>, but I still do get null